# Google Apps Script is Not Detecting the Current Row

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I created a function that's tied to a custom menu item in a google spreadsheet and is meant to detect the current row and perform some checking. The issue is that every time i run the menu item > script it always detect row 1 and not the current script. here's the code for reference:

```
function updateCalendarItems(){


//this function detects the current row and updates the main and follow up calendar events
  //Get the current row
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('<deleted>');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('db_clientvisit');

  Logger.log('Sheet Name: '+sheet.getName()); //this logs the correct sheet name
//  var range = sheet.getActiveCell();
  var rowNum = sheet.getActiveCell().getRow();
  Logger.log(rowNum); //always logs 1
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, 13).getValues(); //always returns the first row
  Logger.log(range);
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Row Num is :'+rowNum+' Column Num is: '+sheet.getActiveCell().getColumn());
  return;
  var range = sheet.getRange(rowNum, 1, 1, 13);
  var row = range.getValues()[0];
  Logger.log(row);
  //open the calendar 
  var calendarID = 'loveyourself.ph_umvj5k6vo45ei0mbh423g97ebg@group.calendar.google.com';
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(calendarID);
  //update the calendar...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()`.

When you use `SpreadsheetApp.openById('<deleted>')`, you're essentially opening up a new *session* of the spreadsheet instead of your active session. So Apps Script isn't able to get the "active" ranges.

Similarly, you may also want to try using [`SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#getcurrentcell).

```
function updateCalendarItems() {
  var currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();
  var rowNum = currentCell.getRow();
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.alert('Row Num is :'+rowNum+' Column Num is: '+currentCell.getColumn());
  return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! it solved my problem! I just have to get the appropriate row at the start of the script before re-opening the active session. Much Appreciated!